# Is there any way to show loading icon till the custom components in home page loads?

Tags: visualforce-component, controller, home-page-component

We included a custom component on top of existing home page standard components. while login into the application, the standard components are shown just after login, but the custom components takes much time to load, sometimes more than 10 mins also.so the user is seeing the blank screen for a long time and get frustated. so had an idea to show the loading icon till the time the data get loaded, but both the loading icon and the data are loading at the same time, again need to wait for long time. please give me the solution how to show the loading icon till the data get retrieved or any other solution to load the home page custom components soon.

Thanks,
Shobana

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on a visualforce page. The solution I used was to set the background image to a loading icon via CSS.

```
background-image: url('/img/loading32.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
```

Then, you have different options:

1. If you have a JS callback when the component finished loading, use that 
   to unset the background image
2. Just make sure the background color of the contents that are loaded late
   are solid, then they will hide the spinning icon

For a list of more icons that are available, see http://free-121d5f44d20-121d603d1c5-121ee2b8103.force.com/force2b/salesforceicons